# How to create a video from single ppt slide

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I'm converting a PowerPoint presentation (`.ppt`) into a `.wmv` video file using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = @"D:\example1.pptx";
    string exportName = "video_of_presentation";
    string exportPath = @"D:\{0}.wmv";

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    ppApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    ppApp.WindowState = PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres = oPresSet.Open(
                    fileName,
                    MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                    MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                    MsoTriState.msoFalse);

    try
    {
        oPres.CreateVideo(exportName);
        oPres.SaveCopyAs(String.Format(exportPath, exportName),
        PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV,
        MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
    }
    finally
    {
        ppApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

It's work great. Now I'm trying to convert a single slide from this presentation into video file. I tried to use this:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var slide in oPres.Slides)
{
    slide.CreateVideo(string.Format("slide{0}", i));
    i++;
}
```

But it seems that slide hasn't `CreateVideo` method.

I think that I need to create a new presentation every iteration and add a slide into it, but I can't understand how to add a slide from my presentation to a new presentation.

I tried this code:

```
Presentation singleSlidePpt = ppApp.Presentations.Add(MsoTriState.msoTrue);
singleSlidePpt.Slides.Add(oPres.Slides[0], CustomLayout);
```

Any suggesions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the presentation to a new name then delete all of the slides you *DON'T* need.

Be sure to do it in reverse order, else you'll get the wrong results.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert a PPT to video, PowerPoint itself has this function "create video".

But I don't know whether it can convert to `.wmv` video directly. If not, you can use a converter after PPT is converted into video, although it seems not the simplest way.